# Why does $f_n\to f$ pointwise imply that $\liminf f_n = f$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**Question:** Why does $f_n\to f$ pointwise imply that $\liminf f_n  = f$?

I know that $\liminf$ is the $\sup$ of the sequence of $\inf$'s of all tail-ends of a sequence, but I can't prove the above question/statement. I've tried to find the answer to this question elsewhere, but I didn't succeed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $\lim f_n(x)$ exists for every $x$, then we always have that $\lim f_n(x)=\liminf f_n(x)=\limsup f_n(x)$ for every $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $\liminf {a_n}$ is the infimum of the set of subsequential limits of $\{a_n\}$ where $\{a_n\}$ is an arbitrary sequence of real numbers.
When $\{a_n\}$ converges to a number $a$, you can easily show that all of its subsequences converges to $a$ as well. In particular, the set of subsequential limits will contain only $a$, so that its infimum will be $a$.